# Acts 10:3 Is the angel that Cornelius saw Jesus?

Tags: acts

Acts 10

1At Caesarea there was a man named Cornelius, a centurion in what was known as the Italian Regiment. 2He and all his family were devout and God-fearing; he gave generously to those in need and prayed to God regularly. 3One day at about three in the afternoon he had a vision. He distinctly saw an angel of God, who came to him and said, “Cornelius!”

4Cornelius stared at him in fear. “What is it, **Lord**?” he asked.

Is this angel the resurrected Jesus?

Answer (score 1):

By no means does the text indicates the angel was Jesus. The mention of Lord by Cornelius, reflects more on his personality than on the angel. This is evident in the fact that Cornelius showed extreme respect to Peter

> “When Peter entered, **Cornelius met him and fell down at his feet and worshiped him**. But Peter lifted him up, saying, “Stand up; I too am a man.””
> ‭‭Acts‬ ‭10:25-26‬ ‭

Cornelius was willing to worship a man, how much more would he not address a heavenly being as Lord.

The text itself indicates it was an Angel and only an angel.

> “And they said, “Cornelius, a centurion, an upright and God-fearing man, who is well spoken of by the whole Jewish nation, was directed **by a holy angel** to send for you to come to his house and to hear what you have to say.””
> ‭‭Acts‬ ‭10:22‬ ‭

Cornelius describes the angel with no features that would identify the risen Jesus, such as wound marks

> “And Cornelius said, “Four days ago, about this hour, I was praying in my house at the ninth hour, and behold, **a man stood before me in bright clothing**”
> ‭‭Acts‬ ‭10:30‬ ‭

Luke narrates that it was only an angel and doesn’t give any indication that it would be Jesus

> “About the ninth hour of the day he saw clearly in a vision **an angel of God** come in and say to him, “Cornelius.””
> ‭‭Acts‬ ‭10:3‬ ‭

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely not! The angel of the Lord in the Old Testament is the pre-incarnate Jesus Christ and he first appears as the angel of the Lord at Genesis 16:7 to Hagar. Please read the rest of the chapter from vs 7 to vs16 and notice what she says at vs13.

His primary purpose in the Old Testament was to be a mediator to Israel, guide them and protect them. Hebrews 1:1-2, "God, after He spoke long ago to the fathers in the prophets in many portions and in many ways, vs2, in these last days has spoken to us in His Son, whom He appointed heir of all things, through whom also He made the world."

I want you to notice something that many people miss from Hebrews 1:1. What's the very first word? "God!" God spoke to the fathers and prophets inspiring them what to say.

Now, regarding Acts 10:3 it says, "About the ninth hour of the day he clearly say in a vision (an) angel of God who had just come in to him and said to him, "Cornelius."

Most Bibles use the word "a" angel or "an" angel and once in a while "the" angel is used. There is a big difference between the words, "a/an" and the word "the."

The chief grammatical function of "an" (or a) is to connote a thing not previously noted or recognized, while "the" connotes a thing previously noted or recognized.

Going back to the Old Testament "the" angel of the Lord is mentioned on numerous occasions as "the" angel of the Lord and is identified at times as God, does things that only God can do and speaks in the first person as God.

At Acts 7 where Stephen is reading the "riot" act to the Jews he says at vs30, "And after forty years had passed, "An" angel appeared to him/Moses in the wilderness of Mount Sinai, in the flame of a burning throne bush." Yes, Stephen did use the word "an."

Now look at vs38, "This is the one who was in the congregation in the wilderness together with "the" angel who was speaking to him on Mount Sinai, and who was with our fathers; and he received living oracles to pass on to you." These "oracles" are "sayings" and is generally used of revelations of God, or here the Ten Commandments are called "living" because they provide guidance for the conduct of life and because they had their source and authorship in the living God.